# How to deal with lag resulting from hundreds of map annotations on an MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm in a situation where there will be 500+ annotations to load onto a map. What some ways that you have dealt with the resulting lag with so many annotations on the map?

One thing I've considered: only loading a portion of the annotations based on the current map region in view. But what happens when they zoom out or move around? Reload based on the region displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MKMapView` has a `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` method ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier%3a)) that I believe you're supposed to use. It looks like it works similarly to `UITableView`'s `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method.

Another thing might be to group clustered pins together into one pin. As you zoom in, you can expand these groups.

**update**: Found a cool open-source library that might be useful for dealing with tons of annotation points: [ADClusterMapView](http://maniacdev.com/2012/10/open-source-library-providing-an-elegant-map-kit-annotation-clustering-solution/)